# Adir Hu - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, song-poetry, passover-seder-hagada, aleph-bet-letters

A popular song sung at the seder is [Adir Hu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adir_Hu). The song contains many phrases of the pattern:

> [Adjective] is He.

that are grouped together alphabetically with a refrain asking for the speedy building of the Third Temple.

The five stanzas of the song contain adjectives that start with the letters א, ב-ד, ה-ח, ט-צ, ק-ת repectively. That's 1, 3, 4, 10, 4 adjectives per stanza. Why is it broken up in this way? Wouldn't it make more sense to do 5, 5, 5, 5, 2 or 4, 5, 4, 5, 4?

Comment: Note that the way it's broken up varies from _hagada_ to _hagada_.

Comment: Re "Wouldn't it make more sense to...", note that many _piyutim_ use a 4-4-4-4-4-4 structure, with the last stanza repeating _kuf_ and _resh_ or _shin_ and _tav_. One *might* have expected the same here.

Comment: @msh210 All good points, as usual.

Comment: If it didn't increase in number, then the "recite the entire stanza in one breath" challenge wouldn't be very difficult or interesting at all.

Comment: I've wondered something similar about "Ashamnu, Bagdnu ..."

Comment: @IsaacMoses There though the pausing at double words might be a post-facto tune thing. For instance, we don't stop at yod.

Comment: http://www.piyut.org.il/articles/835.html

Comment: Maybe it fit a popular tune of the time?

Comment: @user6591 It's possible, but unlikely as tunes tend to be more regular than that.

Comment: @user6591, it's a particularly old Rheinlander niggun. In Jekkisch households, it was once common to sing a Jüdisch-Deutsch version after the Hebrew one. The stanzas are broken up somewhat differently in the JD version though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is something behind this division.
Many songs are divided to 1 ,3,3,3... or 4,4,4,4..,2 to make the whole 22 letters
This verse, each line is standing on its own (Just like Hallel Hagadol or Haderet and Hammuna)
and probably grouped together at some time when the Hagaddah was first printed. In order to make sure there is a need to check some manuscripts and find out how it was written there